# Concatenate $base_url and path_to_theme()

Tags: theming

I'm used to write this kind of code in **.tpl.php** files in order to display images (for instance) :

```
<?php echo $base_url .'/'. path_to_theme();?>
```

I wonder if it would be possible to concatenate **$base_url** and **path_to_theme()** into one single command/variable ?

Comment: Do you mean setting a variable as `$path = $base_url . '/' . path_to_theme()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `hook_preprocess($vars)` create a new variable called `path_to_theme` in $vars by including the following (where `$hook` is page, node, block etc)

```
function mymodule_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['path_to_theme'] = base_path().path_to_theme();
}
```

Now in virtually all of your theme's template you can use the variable `$path_to_theme` and it will be the contents of `base_path().path_to_theme()`

Note, that you can put this in a custom module, or replace `mymodule` with the name of your theme and you can place it in your theme's `template.php`

You can use [node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6), page, and other "hook" specific preprocess functions if you only wish to add this variable to specific content of your site.

There are many options for preprocessing nodes, pages etc. which can be read up in:
[Setting up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)](http://drupal.org/node/223430)

Also be sure to read up on the [Default baseline variables](http://drupal.org/node/226776) such as:

> **$directory** The theme path relative to
>   the base install. example:
>   "sites/all/themes/myTheme"

Answer (score 0):

You can theme_preprocess_node() or theme_preprocess_page() in your template.php file in your theme and create your concatenated path there so it is accessible in template files.

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_path'] = base_path() . path_to_theme();
}

function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_path'] = base_path() . path_to_theme();
}
```

Then $theme_path is always available in your template files.